# How to force log4j to write to a logfile not from main thread

Tags: android, logging, log4j, android-strictmode

On slow device got STRICT MODE exception:

```
 D/StrictMode: StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=494 ms: android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskWriteViolation: policy=87 violation=1
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onWriteToDisk(StrictMode.java:732)
        at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.write(BlockGuard.java:170)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:300)
        at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:164)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.QuietWriter.flush(QuietWriter.java:59)
        at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:324)
        at org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.subAppend(RollingFileAppender.java:276)
        at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:162)
        at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251)
        at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.debug(Category.java:260)
```

on **the first** logging operation in the **main thread**.
I'm using log4j with `RollingFileAppender`.

Does it write to a file in main thread? That is weird in my opinion...
How can I force `log4j` to write to a logfile from some other thread, not from main thread?

Answer (score 0):

"Simple".

Create the Log4j appender, and invoke the logs always from a background thread.

You can use for example an AsyncTask `doInBackground` method to do the calls.